Unable to fetch the TypeInformation of this org.apache.iceberg.io.WriteResult. When using the Iceberg's FlinkSink in Iceberg stream sink
Currenly i am ingesting data into iceberg using the Flink Iceberg sink library. I am using the FlinkSink class to write the data into iceberg. For the performance reason i have disabled the kryo serialization env.getConfig().disableGenericTypes(); when executing the program i am currently getting exception.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Generic types have been disabled in the ExecutionConfig and type org.apache.iceberg.io.WriteResult is treated as a generic type.
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.GenericTypeInfo.createSerializer(GenericTypeInfo.java:87)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.createSerializer(StreamGraph.java:1037)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.addOperator(StreamGraph.java:427)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.addOperator(StreamGraph.java:399)
Does the iceberg flinkSink doesnt have a class to serialize the WriteResult class? or is there something i am missing?
I was expecting that that the library would have a serializer to serialize the WriteResult class.
